# looker Studio issue

Tags: graph, looker

I set up a dashboard in looker studio and two of the graphs( they should show newest dates in the MTD and YTD) but instead each time i open the dashboard as if i were an user, i see the oldest dates on top.
this is what should look like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PpbZ9.png)
when i open the dashboard, this is how it looks each time:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f60R8.png)
how do i fix that?

i tried adjusting the setup/style. tried grouping, but that makes it worst.